# "You cannot register at this time" error when trying to register on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: support, status-review, error-message, registration

I wanted to upvote the feature request [*Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message)

But when I attempt to create the account on meta.stackexchange.com I get this dialog

[image: error screenshot]

The "Log in" link just leads back to the same error message page.

What's the problem?

I understand probably this question actually belongs on meta.stackexchange.com instead of meta.stackoverflow.com, but I could not post it on there for the obvious reason

Comment: The message says "If you continue to find this error, contact us.". Did you do that?

Comment: Uhhh, that's odd. I mean I could move this to Meta Stack Exchange for you but then you couldn't reply, which is probably generally unhelpful...

Comment: A potentially related bug report on MSE: ["You cannot register at this time" when trying to join a new Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383709/335251)

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine It leads to a form which I've filled out, but I'm not hopeful there will be any response on that